# JQuery AJAX Navigation using load() reload resources several times (audio)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-load

I'm using JQuery `load()` function (*wrapper of `$.ajax()`*) to get the content of a determined `DIV`.

But I encountered with the next problem;  `load()` **gets** (*and load, obviously*) **the resources like audio and video; so the page does not work as fast as it should.**

I'm using the next code:

```
var container =  $("#container"), url = "mydomain.com/page2/ #content";

container.load(url, function(data) {
    // Set the new title.
    document.title = $(data).filter('title').text();
});
```

## Summary:

**Each time the user browses the page, the audio reloaded as a GET request.**

[image: Audio reloaded]

**And the music overlaps, sounding all at once...**

## Representation of the page whose content I want to retrieve (*I will use only the HTML inside #content*):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Title of the page</title>  
    </head>
    <body>

       <div id="content"> Hello <b>world</b> this is the content I want to get.</div>

       <audio autoplay loop preload="auto">
           <source src="mydomain/wp-content/themes/mytheme/resources/audio/road.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/> 
           <source src="mydomain/wp-content/themes/mytheme/resources/audio/road.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/> 
       </audio>

    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how to avoid the load of resources (*audio, at least*) outside of `#content`?

Comment: Store it in localstorage.

Comment: @Nit I don't see how the HTML5 `localStorage` could help me ... May you explain a little more, please?

Comment: When you need your data, check if you've stored in localstorage before. If you have, take it from there instead of Ajaxing it. If it isn't there, Ajax it and store it there so next time you don't have to Ajax it.

Comment: @Nit The problem is that I do not want at any time receive audio by AJAX; I just want the HTML content of a specific div (`#content`). But for some reason, I also loads the audio resources ...

Comment: Let me get u right. You want to load the content of <div id="content"> without the audio that is under it, isn't it ? And you want to load that into the div with container id isn't it ?

Comment: @JohnMax Yes, that is! Maybe my explanation isn't good, sorry. The `#container` is on the page which I using the `load()` method ; and works well (*loads the contents of `#content`*). I just do not want to load the audio resource.

Comment: @tomloprod  ok. I have a jquery function that can help you achieve that . However it will not be an edit of your code but it will work. Should I add it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, such as `load()` function reloads the resources like `audio`, I implemented an control in the second page for checking if the request is an AJAX request :

```
// Code of the "page.php" file.

$Is_AJAX = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ? true : false;

// If is an AJAX request we don't need the header
if(!$Is_AJAX) get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div  id="content">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                comments_template();
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>

// If is an AJAX request we don't need the header (the audio resources are in the footer).
<?php if(!$Is_AJAX) get_footer(); ?>
```

In this way we also **get the page load fastest**, since only we obtain the content of the wanted page (*ignoring the header.php and footer.php of a Wordpress theme*).

The only downside I see him is I can't pick up the title of the requested page (*since it's in the header*), but I created a hidden `div` which contain the title of each page for solve this problem:

```
// This code goes in the "page.php" file.
<div class="hidden" id="title_Page"><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[rel*=charger_partiel]', function(f) { 

f.preventDefault();

var myId_to_update_here = $(this).data('ajax'); 

var myId_to_load_from_other_page = $(this).data('direction');       

    var afficher_chargement = $(this).data('icon');

    var chargement_devant_lien = $(this).data('filter');

    var image_de_chargement = '<img src="images/facebook_style_loader.gif" />';



    if(chargement_devant_lien!='')
    {
        $('#'+chargement_devant_lien).html(image_de_chargement);
    }
    //Fin de l'affichage du chargement si l'id du span du devant lien est mis   


    if(afficher_chargement=='Oui')
    {
        $('#'+myId_to_update_here).html(image_de_chargement);
    }
    //Fin de l'affichage du chargement si le data-icon='Oui'




  $('#'+myId_to_update_here).load($(this).attr('href')+' #'+myId_to_load_from_other_page




  , function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if(textStatus == 'error') {
                $('#'+myId_to_update_here).html('<p>Oupps.. There was an error making the AJAX request. Maybe your internet connection is slowing down.</p>');
            }
        });



        if(chargement_devant_lien!='')
    {
        $('#'+chargement_devant_lien).html('');
    }
    //Fin de l'affichage du chargement si l'id du span du devant lien est mis



  return false;
});
```

Now Html

All you have to do now is to set the parametters if your div are in place on each page it should work

```
<a href="mypage.php" rel="charger_partiel" data-direction="content"    data-ajax="container">charger_partiel</a>
```

Depending on the page you are and you want to load from and to

```
<a href="mypage.php" rel="charger_partiel" data-direction="container"    data-ajax="content">charger_partiel</a>
```

Mypage.php is the page that you want to load the informations from ( not the page on which you are)

data direction shows where you want to load it from (the div)

and data ajax where you want to load it to

This is based on the latest versiob of jquery. If you are not using the latest version, instead of on click you will have to go for click directly.

Comment: Does exactly the same as my function; still loading the `audio` resource. I don't know what happens with `load()`...

Comment: Does it show any error in firebug ? If you have firebug check for error and let me know. It may be another script that is interfering with jquery

Comment: No, he doesn't show any error, as my own script. But the audio resource is reloaded

Comment: Can u put online w live demo of the two pages so that I may check because it is working on my end